# This field 'x' does not have a default value

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
{
        Schema::create('registry', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('age_gap');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->integer('phone');
        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

on the column 'age_gap' i am trying to save something like this '13-19 years'. What should be the data type in that column

Comment: Assuming you're adding '13-19' the type `string` should be fine. Please add the code that attempts to save the data to the database and your `registry` model.

Comment: @Peppermintology There is no way you can save the whole of this '13-19 years'?

Comment: `'13-19 years'` is a `string` and so should be fine to store in a database field that is defined as a `string`. So your migration is technically correct. This is why I suggest you add the code responsible for adding the data and your model as the error quite possible is elsewhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it as:

1. a string and manually convert it back to 2 integers when reading it
2. 2 separate integer columns as min_age and max_age for example